# Does this sequence of product of two primes always exist

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

Consider a sequence $A: a_1, a_2, a_3 .. a_n$ such that each element of this sequence is product of two primes from $p_1, p_2 .. p_m$ so that:

1. Each $a_i$ is distinct.
2. $m$ is the least integer so that $\frac{m(m-1)}{2} \ge n$
3. Any three consecutive elements of sequence are coprime, but any two are not.

For example,

1. for $n = 3$, we have $m = 3$ and so taking the 3 primes as $a,b,c$, we can say the sequence $A$ is $ab, bc, ac$
2. For $n = 4$, $m = 4$ and $A: ab, bc, cd, da$
3. For $n = 6$, $m = 4$ and $A: ab, bd, da, ac, cd, db$

*The question is to show that such a sequence exists for any $n$.*

If this sequence exists for all $n$, is there a **simple pattern** for $A$ ?\

**Edit**

There was an error in example 3, no such sequence exists for $n=6$.

Comment: There is a problem in your example for $n=6$: $bd$ and $db$ are equal.

Comment: @ajotatxe sorry I overlooked this one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example for $n=6$ doesn't work, because the terms $bd$ and $db$ are the same number, and in fact no valid sequence exists in this case.

This is really a graph theory question: terms of the sequence correspond to edges of the complete graph $K_m$ and the conditions require that two consecutive edges share a vertex but three consecutive edges don't. Equivalently, we are looking for a trail of length $n$. If $m$ is odd there will always be such a trail (because $K_m$ is Eulerian), but if $m$ is even and $n$ is close to the maximum value it won't exist.